# Why do we use $n-2(k+1)$ when we are testing for differences in regression functions across groups?

Tags: inference

I bumped into my econometrics book (Wooldridge 6th edition) over testing whether slopes and intercept are the same for two different groups (men and women, white and black etc.).

It says that the hypothesis that each $\beta$ is the same across the two groups is $k+1$ which I understand, but then it says that for the unrestricted model it is going to be $n-2(k+1)$ and I cannot figure it out why is it like that.

Can you guys dumb it down as much as possible so that my brain can get over it?

Why do we use $n-2(k+1)$ when we are testing for differences in regression functions across groups?

Script from the book:

"In the general model with K explanatory variables and an intercept, suppose we have two groups; call them g=1 and g=2. We would like to test whether the intercept in all slopes are the same across the two groups. Write the model as: $$y=\beta_{g,0} + \beta_{g,1}x_1 + ... + \beta_{g,k}x_k + u $$ for g=1 and g=2. The hypothesis that each $\beta$  is the same across the two groups involves $k+1$  restrictions. The unrestricted model, which we can think of as having a group dummy variable and k interaction terms in addition to the intercept and variables themselves, has $n-2(k+1)$ degrees of freedom"

I hope the above paragraph helps.

This is the sentence that I don't fully understand

"The unrestricted model, which we can think of as having a group dummy variable and k interaction terms in addition to the intercept and variables themselves, has $n-2(k+1)$ degrees of freedom"

I know what n is (sample size) I know that k is the number of slope coefficients and that the 1 stands for the intercept, but why do we multiply with 2?

Comment: Can you give more information? What are k and n?

Comment: n is the sample size and k are the terms in beta (slope coefficients)

Comment: I think the author is talking about degrees of freedom.

Comment: Since what you write is lacking important information, can you offer one or more quotes from the book that make it clearer what the situation is?